# Auto generate space in uk postcodes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way when user typing a UK postcodes in input field then generate auto space between string with respect to UK postcodes.

If user type in input field

```
CB30QB becomes CB3 0QB
N12NL becomes N1 2NL
CB249LQ becomes CB24 9LQ
OX144FB becomes OX1 44FB
OX145FB becomes OX14 5FB
```

I am trying like this way

Fiddle [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mg1m0cp9/)

Comment: How do you know that you have to split `OX144FB` differently to `OX145FB`?

Comment: @Nick you don't OP has split them incorrectly.  It should be OX14 4FB.  Adding space is easy - the inward code (the right-hand part) is *always* 3 characters.

Comment: @freedomn-m that information would have made it much easier to answer the question... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#postcode").keyup(function() {
      var postcode = $("#postcode").val();
      var parts = postcode.match(/^([A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}[A-Z]?)\s*(\d[A-Z]{2})$/);
      if (!parts) {
        return;
      }
      parts.shift();
      $("#postcode").val(parts.join(' '));
    });
  });
</script>

<input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" class="form-control" value="">
```

Comment: Please explain DV!

Comment: Thank you for answer but I need that when user type a postcode in input field then auto generate space between string

Comment: Check it now @Arslan

Comment: its showing errors Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shift' of null"

Comment: And now? You can handle the wrong input what you want, an alert, clearing the input and so on @Arslan

Comment: Please stop alert("No Correct input"); showing its disturbing when user enter a postcode

Comment: sorry for its my checking mistake its working what I need like that. Thank you for supporting